# WindowsXP: Multiple Desktops On One Monitor (Like Linux) (C#)

Tags: c#, desktop, screen

Is there a way to create a second Desktop screen in C# - just like they do in Linux? I've never done this before but I find the idea very interesting.

I have tried a few samples out there, none of which would even compile. One of them had 294 errors when I tried to debug. Wow! However, trying to find these samples again (a year later) is proving to be very difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look at  [Vista/XP Virtual Desktop Manager [codeplex.com]](http://www.codeplex.com/vdm)?

Comment: Ah, good link. Thank you for this, I'm downloading it now to check it out.

Comment: Great link. :-) I probably won't be using this as I hate using samples/ other people's projects. But I'll definitely be able to learn from this.

Comment: It's open source code under MS-PL, which means the authors specifically allow/encourage you to use their work. There's really no harm in using the code (obviously it's good ethics to give them credit, and if you find bugs or can improve their code otherwise, contribute back).

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have two options for this:

1. [`CreateDesktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682124(VS.85).aspx). Advantage is that the operating system supports this for ages out of the box, disadvantage is that processes are confined to the desktop they start on; you can't move windows between desktops.
2. Manage everything yourself. That means hiding and showing windows when changing desktops. Certainly more flexible, but also much more work.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'm looking into CreateDesktop now. The CreateDesktop seems like the better option in my case since I have no current intentions of moving windows to another screen.

I'll also keep in mind the second option for when I need to move things between screens. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [SysInternals Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx). Basic stuff, no fancy things. Mark Russinovich is usually a reliable source.